# Как добавить к параметру +1 день?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос:

```
declare
    @StartDate DateTime='2016-01-01',
    @EndDate DateTime='2016-02-29'
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select id, ModifiedAt
From Deals
Where ModifiedAt between @StartDate and @EndDate
END
```

Как сделать при интервалах даты `'2016-01-01'` по `'2016-02-29'` запрос выполнялся по `2016-01-01` по `2016-03-01`?
То есть нужно  в `Where` добавить условия +1 Day

Comment: Может, опишете проблему поточнее? Зачем вам такое понадобилось? Подозреваю, что связано с тем, что в MdifiedAt значение хранится дата с временем...

Comment: @Vasil Baymurzin, Да в ModifiedAt значение хранится дата с временем.  Если я беру ModifiedAt between StartDate and EndDate то не попадает записи у которых дата к примеру 2016-02-29 18:15:42.087

Comment: как вариант, можно в условии у ModifiedAt отсечь время, но при этом при наличии индексов по этому полю, если не ошибаюсь, будет не очень эффективно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

С помощью функции [`dateadd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
Where ModifiedAt between @StartDate and dateadd(day, 1, @EndDate)
```

Можно добавлять день, час, месяц, год, неделю и т.п. - это задаётся первым параметром. Второй параметр - сколько соответствующих интервалов добавить. Последний - то к чему добавлять. Замечу, что можно добавлять отрицательные величины.

---

Вижу, у вас это в процедуре с параметром, иногда удобнее прибавлять день к параметру перед вызовом процедуры (например, если происходит вызов из внешнего приложения), оставив в ней:

```
Where ModifiedAt between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

но, это конечно - как вам удобнее.

Да, и, для дат часто делают проверку интервала с нижней границей включённой, а верхней - исключенной, чтобы если сделка совершена ровно в промежутке, она не попадала в два интервала одновременно:

```
Where ModifiedAt >= @StartDate and ModifiedAt < @EndDate
```

T.е. если у нас допустим `@StartDate = 2016-01-01` a `@EndDate = 2016-03-01`, то возьмутся записи с `2016-01-01 00:00:00.000` примерно по `2016-02-29 23:59:59`.

Comment: все это красиво и однозначно, если исходное значение datetime не содержит в себе времени суток. Накинули день, и хорошо. Если же на входе может быть произвольное значение, то накинув день - мы также получим значение с каким-то временем. Действительноли это требовалось? Если имелось ввиду - округление до ближайшей большей даты - то это делается так:     начало текущего дня: SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()),0)    . Начало следующего дня: SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()),1)

Comment: в данном случае вместо GETDATE() нужно вставить @EndDate

Comment: или окончательно:  Where ModifiedAt between @StartDate and DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @EndDate),1)